# Enable transcription of PSSession with GPOs for Remoting + Transcripts

Tags: powershell, logging, powershell-remoting

I have a OU including machines (**R**) for which I enabled PowerShell Remoting and Transcription via GPOs.
Only a certain machine (**I**) can initialize remote sessions to this machines. This machine also has transcripts enabled.
But say I open a powershell on **I**. Imidiately a new transcript is created on a network share.
Then I type `Enter-PSSession $R` - this command also gets logged.
But as soon as I am remotly connected to **R**, nothing gets transcripted anymore.
In other words, for every command where `[remote-computername]` starts the line, I am blind.

I could manually start the transcript with `Start-Transcript` / `Stop-Transcript`, I am aware, but I want it done automatically.

How can I ensure, that everything I see in my PowerShell is transcripted?